# Why am I seeing calculations ran on 64-bit excel being roughly 5 to 6 times slower than on 32-bit excel?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, 32bit-64bit

I am testing potential performance improvements with heavy formulas on large data sets and I am trialing copying down several SUMPRODUCT formulas down to end of data set then calculating in manual mode and timing the calculation time for both the 64bit office device and 32bit office device.

For a sample I had the below results:
32bit - 7 minutes
64bit - 1 hour

Is there any reason that the below code would run so much differently? I would expect the opposite if any difference.

```
Function SysMemory()
    Dim oInstance
    Dim colInstances
    Dim dRam                  As Double
    Set colInstances = GetObject("winmgmts:").ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_PhysicalMemory")
    For Each oInstance In colInstances
        dRam = dRam + oInstance.Capacity
    Next
    SysMemory = dRam / 1024 / 1024 & "MB"
End Function
```

```
Sub Calc_Timer()

    ' Setup and start timer
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Dim StartTime As Double
    Dim TimeTaken As String
    StartTime = Timer


    ' Find last row in spreadsheet based on Column C then copy down all formulas
    Dim Lastrow As Long
    Lastrow = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("S2:Y102").FillDown


    ' Calculate then paste as values except for top row to keep live formulas
    Application.Calculate
    Range("S3:Y102").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    ' Check office version
    Dim OfficeVersion As String
    If Win64 Then
        OfficeVersion = "Excel Version: V" & Application.Version & " 64-Bit"
    Else
        OfficeVersion = "Excel Version: V" & Application.Version & " 32-Bit"
    End If

    ' Report time taken
    TimeTaken = Format((Timer - StartTime) / 86400, "hh:mm:ss")

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

    MsgBox "Time Taken: " & TimeTaken & " (hours, minutes, seconds)" & vbCrLf & _
            "Processor: " & CreateObject("WScript.Shell").RegRead("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\System\CentralProcessor\0\ProcessorNameString") & vbCrLf & _
            "RAM: " & SysMemory() & vbCrLf & OfficeVersion & vbCrLf & "Operating System: " & Application.OperatingSystem

End Sub
```

An example of the formulas are below:

```
S2:

=SUMPRODUCT(--(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($C2,'Raw Data'!$A:$A)))*(((ROUNDDOWN(H2,0)>='Raw Data'!$L:$L)*(ROUNDDOWN(H2,0)<='Raw Data'!$W:$W))+((ROUNDUP(I2,0)>='Raw Data'!$L:$L)*(ROUNDUP(I2,0)<='Raw Data'!$W:$W))+((ROUNDDOWN(H2,0)<='Raw Data'!$L:$L)*(ROUNDUP(I2,0)>='Raw Data'!$W:$W))>0))

T2:

=SUMPRODUCT(--(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($C2,'Raw Data'!$A:$A)))*(((ROUNDDOWN(H2,0)>='Raw Data'!$L:$L)*(ROUNDDOWN(H2,0)<='Raw Data'!$W:$W))+((ROUNDUP(I2,0)>='Raw Data'!$L:$L)*(ROUNDUP(I2,0)<='Raw Data'!$W:$W))+((ROUNDDOWN(H2,0)<='Raw Data'!$L:$L)*(ROUNDUP(I2,0)>='Raw Data'!$W:$W))>0),'Raw Data'!$G:$G)

U2:

=SUMPRODUCT(--(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($C2,'Raw Data'!$A:$A)))*(((ROUNDDOWN(H2,0)>='Raw Data'!$L:$L)*(ROUNDDOWN(H2,0)<='Raw Data'!$W:$W))+((ROUNDUP(I2,0)>='Raw Data'!$L:$L)*(ROUNDUP(I2,0)<='Raw Data'!$W:$W))+((ROUNDDOWN(H2,0)<='Raw Data'!$L:$L)*(ROUNDUP(I2,0)>='Raw Data'!$W:$W))>0),'Raw Data'!$H:$H)

V2:

=U2/T2

W2:

=COUNTIF(B3:B2305,B2)

X2:

=ROUNDDOWN(H2,0)

Y2:

=ROUNDUP(H2,0)
```

Comment: Are they both the same Office version (and workbook format) other than bitness? Also what is `Win64` - a variable? (you don't appear to be using conditional compilation)

Comment: Please see below versions:
32bit - 16.0.4966.1000
64bit - 16.0.4266.1001

Win64 is just to check if it is 64bit or not to show in a msgbox. Screenshots are taken on time taken to calculate and this is to provide PC & Excel versions and specs to aid in identifying how the result was calculated.

Comment: Didn't really answer my question about `Win64` - is that a variable you declared? I suspect there's something else interfering on the 64bit version. Try running Excel in safe mode and then redo the timings. It shouldn't take that long.

Comment: @Rory, I suspect the OP doesn't realize `Win64` is a [compiler constant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Concepts/Getting-Started/compiler-constants) specifically for conditional compilation, and can't be used in random `if` statements. @Andrew: If it does work there, then it has to be defined someplace else. Where is it being defined/assigned?

Comment: @T.J.L., Yes I didnt realise I had to use #If instead of the typical If statement due to it being a compiler constant. This also now shows as 64bit instead of 32bit while running on the 32bit system.

Comment: @Rory, I will try to run it again tomorrow in safe mode and without a macro timer, I will use a manual timer and report back any improvements. In the meantime any other advice or amendments would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If the `#If Win64 then` branch is executing, then it can't be 32bit. The formulas are very inefficient as they are testing entire columns.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling the "Fault Tolerant Heap":
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/win7appqual/fault-tolerant-heap

`Regedit: HKLM\Software\Microsoft\FTH\Enabled to 0`

Or run this in a cmd box with admin privileges (which will reset all FTH's for all applications)

`Rundll32.exe fthsvc.dll,FthSysprepSpecialize`